# Vue3 Check if a Slot is Empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Is there a Vue3 equivalent to the following Vue2 method:

```js
methods: {
   hasSlot(name) {
      return !!this.$slots[name]
   }
}
```

in Vue3's Composition API?

I've tried:

```js
setup({slots}) {
   const hasSlot = (name) => {
      return !!slots[name];
   }

   return { hasSlot }

}
```

but it isn't returning the expected value as `slots` is undefined (per error out in console).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As pointed out in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187278/vue3-check-if-a-slot-is-empty#comment120513761_68187278), [`setup()`'s *second argument*](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#arguments) (the `context`) contains the component's `slots`. The first argument is for the component's `props`.

```js
export default {
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    const hasSlot = name => !!slots[name]
    return { hasSlot }
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-using-slots?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

The slots are also exposed in the template as `$slots`, so you could replace `hasSlot(slotName)` with `$slots[slotName]` or just `$slots.SLOTNAME` (e.g., `$slots.footer`):

```html
<template>
  <footer v-if="$slots.footer">
    <h3>footer heading</h3>
    <slot name="footer" />
  </footer>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-using-slots-ervj9f?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: But what if you don't have named slots and want to check if the default slot is empty?

Comment: @hitautodestruct Use `v-if="$slots.default"`.

Comment: my $slots.default is a function, so is always true, how to solve this?

Comment: @RadianJheng a possible solution is to use this very verbose way:
useSlots().default()?.[0]?.children?.length > 0

Comment: This solution does not work, as said before $slots.default is likely a function. Calling it and measuring the length of resulting nodes, triggers runtime Vue warning - which is also a no go.

Answer (score 43):

Now, in Vue3 composition API , you can use `useSlots`.

```js
<script setup>
const slots = useSlots()
const hasSlot = (name) => {
    return !!slots[name];
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Just for the record: `useSlots()` returns an object where the keys are the names of the slots. The unnamed slot has the `default` key.